# Refactor LINQ queries in different controllers in MVC4 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, refactoring, dry

I am trying to apply the DRY (Do Not Repeat Yourself) to my MVC4 program.

I have two LINQ queries in two different controllers.

The queries are the same.

What is the best way to make the query available to both controllers.

Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a BL layer?

Comment: No, I am using an Entity Framework data model and accessing the data in the controller with LINQ queries.

Comment: Right from your controller? Not a very good idea. If you decide to have a WebAPI that does the exact same operations for a mobile app, you're going to repeat yourself quite a lot. Controllers should be nothing more than a router, calling relevant methods in your BL layer. The BL layer is the one that should be doing all the logic, not the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've said, the LINQ statements are the same, correct? For example, getting a list of active hourly employees, in stock inventory items or such.

In this situation, it would probably be best to add these commonly used methods to your Entity model. If you generated the classes, they're partial classes so you would simply create a partial class with the routines you need to retrieve the commonly used data. This class would go in your models folder. It would look something like this...

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public partial class MyEntities
    {

        IQueryable<InventoryItem> InStockInventoryItems()
        {
            return this.InventoryItems.Where(m => m.Quantity > 0);
        }

    }
}
```